# configure the varnish shared cache

Tags: caching, varnish, shared

We have enabled Auto-scaling for our web application, we are using Varnish as caching layer & it will store everything into RAM memory.

But when the new server comes up it is again fetching the pages from disk, is it possible to move ram memory to the newly launched server.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't in the free version of Varnish.

Varnish Enterprise do have a feature for replication/clustering
[Varnish enterprise](https://www.varnish-software.com/plus/varnish-high-availability/)

> **Varnish High Availability features**
>
> **Cross-server content replication:** Greater resilience and boosted performance for your backend setup. Performance is enhanced by cutting cache miss rates in half.
>
> **Lightweight high-performance architecture:** Requires minimal
>   configuration and resources. The overhead from the replication stream
>   is low, meaning that you get the benefits of more resilience and
>   performance at a low cost.
>
> **SSL/TLS support:** Protected connections
>   using TLS. All your data transfers can be encrypted, including those
>   between data centers.
>
> **Cluster support:** VHA can replicate its cache to a potentially infinite number of nodes.
>
> **Simpler VCL:** All VHA in a replicated cluster can share the same configuration, making management easier and opening up the ability to use VHA in conjunction with  Varnish Administration Console.
>
> **Automated VCL:** VCL is now more consistent across nodes, and can be generated from cluster definition, which reduces human errors with more automation.
>
> **Bandwidth load reduction:** VHA will now issue HEAD requests rather than
>   GET requests, which effectively halves the network replication load.